# How to get subnet mask using .net?

Tags: c#, network-programming, ip, subnet

I want to get client subnet mask using c#.

How can I get it?

Comment: try [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dgorti/archive/2005/10/04/477078.aspx)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all, check [`NetworkInterface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.aspx) class first. There are a lot of information in it. And these articles will be helpful for you:

- [`IP Address Calculations with C# (Subnetmasks, Networks, …)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/knom/ip-address-calculations-with-c-subnetmasks-networks)
- [`Get Subnet Mask`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/GetSubnetMask.htm)
- [`Finding subnet mask from IP4 address using c#`](http://weblogs.asp.net/razan/archive/2009/09/25/finding-subnet-mask-from-ip4-address-using-c.aspx)

Comment: You are talking about local network interfaces (expect for the last link), not remote...

Comment: @Eugene He didn't said any thing about remote connection. Why downvote?

Comment: What about IPv6?

Comment: @SonerGönül: I don't recall if I saw it to be honest but I was trying to say you should put something addressing this in your answer :)