# Finding the subnet mask of your local PC

Tags: c#, ip, subnet

I having a bit of difficulty trying to get some subnet information off my local PC. This code "technically" runs fine because it contains no warning or errors, however when the application is run, all that is returned is "0.0.0.0" I have other very similar code within my application requesting the IP address, Default Gateway etc. and that works perfectly fine, so I'm at a loss at the moment as to why this isn't returning the subnet mask. Any help would be appreciated! Is there something really obvious that I'm missing out which is why this is not working?

```
        NetworkInterface[] subnetInterface = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        foreach (NetworkInterface subnetMask in subnetInterface)
        {
            UnicastIPAddressInformationCollection UnicastIPInfoCol = subnetMask.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses;
            foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation UnicatIPInfo in UnicastIPInfoCol)
            {
                subnetMaskLabel.Content = UnicatIPInfo.IPv4Mask;

            }
```

I have 3 network adapters, 2 VMWare which are currently disabled for the purpose of this application, and 1 Local Area connection which is enabled so that the application only reviews that connection.

*UPDATE* 
I have attempted to solve the issue of getting "255.0.0.0" and not been succesfull. When I place breakpoints within my application when the information is passed down in the " subnetMaskLabel.Content = UnicatIPInfo.IPv4Mask;" syntax the value stored is the correct subnet mask, however it is displaying an incorrect one, any ideas on how this might be solved?

Comment: see the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901436/how-to-get-subnet-mask-using-net

Comment: Thanks Mitz, I will re-review those links to make sure I did not do anything wrong, however I have tried them and I still got the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking at a non ipv4 address. Try this for the internetwork addresses:

```
    public static void GetSubnetMask()
    {
        foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation unicastIPAddressInformation in adapter.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
            {
                if (unicastIPAddressInformation.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(unicastIPAddressInformation.IPv4Mask);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! We've made progression, however it is only coming up as "255.0.0.0" now.