# c# get the ip adress of the subnet network

Tags: c#

how can i get the subnet range of a network ? for example my ip is `192.168.1.23` inside the network subnet range network is `192.168.1.0 - 255` is there any method that provide you with this using c# or any other libraries that can help ? 

- i tried to make some swich to some common local ip adress but its still cannot be used in a production since there is an uncountable cases depends on how its been structed .

 - i tried to search for some helpful solutions but i couldn't find any helpful topic about it

thanks in advance .

Comment: A network does not have an IP address, do you mean gateway IP? Or subnet range?

Comment: @Crowcoder yes sir a subnet range

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901436/how-to-get-subnet-mask-using-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
public static class IPAddressExtensions
{
    public static IPAddress GetBroadcastAddress(this IPAddress address, IPAddress subnetMask)
    {
        byte[] ipAdressBytes = address.GetAddressBytes();
        byte[] subnetMaskBytes = subnetMask.GetAddressBytes();

        if (ipAdressBytes.Length != subnetMaskBytes.Length)
            throw new ArgumentException("Lengths of IP address and subnet mask do not match.");

        byte[] broadcastAddress = new byte[ipAdressBytes.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < broadcastAddress.Length; i++)
        {
            broadcastAddress[i] = (byte)(ipAdressBytes[i] | (subnetMaskBytes[i] ^ 255));
        }
        return new IPAddress(broadcastAddress);
    }

    public static IPAddress GetNetworkAddress(this IPAddress address, IPAddress subnetMask)
    {
        byte[] ipAdressBytes = address.GetAddressBytes();
        byte[] subnetMaskBytes = subnetMask.GetAddressBytes();

        if (ipAdressBytes.Length != subnetMaskBytes.Length)
            throw new ArgumentException("Lengths of IP address and subnet mask do not match.");

        byte[] broadcastAddress = new byte[ipAdressBytes.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < broadcastAddress.Length; i++)
        {
            broadcastAddress[i] = (byte)(ipAdressBytes[i] & (subnetMaskBytes[i]));
        }
        return new IPAddress(broadcastAddress);
    }

    public static bool IsInSameSubnet(this IPAddress address2, IPAddress address, IPAddress subnetMask)
    {
        IPAddress network1 = address.GetNetworkAddress(subnetMask);
        IPAddress network2 = address2.GetNetworkAddress(subnetMask);

        return network1.Equals(network2);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to take an answer from somewhere else, you should cite your source so that people can appreciate the author. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/knom/2008/12/31/ip-address-calculations-with-c-subnetmasks-networks